# Add Textview one under the other in loop

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to add textviews one just bellow another but when I run the code, it all gets stacked together. Here is the code:

```
RelativeLayout constraintLayout;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

private void createTable() {
        RelativeLayout textRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        relativeLayout.addView(textRelativeLayout);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText("TextView " + String.valueOf(i));
            setTextViewAttributes(textView);
            textView.setId(i);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, textView.getId());
            textRelativeLayout.addView(textView);
        }
    }
```

Since first I'm trying to make it work, I'm only setting dummy text for now. Is it my code that is wrong? Or did I miss a Param?

Comment: You're either not seeing anything, or seeing one item only, right?
You are adding a rule to params but never using params.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use `param`.

It should be `textRelativeLayout.addView(textView , param);`
Or use `textView.setLayoutParams(params)`

And I think the rule should be (I'm not tested this ):

`params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, previousTextView.getId());`

Also it is better to use a `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation to add view under other view.

Comment: Actually he's using params from the method setTextViewAttributes() I guess. First time he enters the loop he's not using it immediately because he wants to align it to the bottom of the previous view, this is why he's setting the addRule() later on. It's not the best way to add textViews in a view. There's a much simpler way, I don't know what your'e doing wrong in ur case. Check my answer.

Comment: setting  textLinearLayout.addView(textView, params); gives the same result unfortunelly

Comment: @Phacer do you call LinearLayout.setOrientation(vertical) ?

Comment: Yes, when I was using Linear layout I had that line, textLinearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL); I guess it had the same effect, right?

Comment: @Phacer yes this is true, if you can provide more details of your code and xml file please

Comment: Actually both of you were right, it works either way, somehow I had that there but it wasn't working, and now the code works when adding the setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL)...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`.

Make sure you set the orientation to '`vertical`' for the `LinearLayout` as well.

No need to add rules to params like you're doing for the `LinearLayout`. They will get order from top to bottom automatically.

Comment: I was using Linear before, the problem is the textviews were getting side by side and not aligned verctically. Tried also setting their index on addView but didn't work.

Comment: u need to set orientation to vertical!

Comment: That reallly worked! I was adding that on the layout, turns out you need to add that programatically aswell...

Comment: If you are creating a new layout every time, then surely you need to set it programmatically. `LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this)` is a new layout. However, if you say `LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.ll)` will have the orientation you already set on that layout